# QT Static version does not include external targetted libs

Tags: cmake, static-libraries, static-linking, qt6, saprfc

so I use static version,
all works fine, app exe is generated with all standard and qt dlls so its fine to open in any windows machine.

However the external libraries i link against the project are NOT included in this...

cmake:

```
...
set_target_properties(${PROJECT} PROPERTIES
    WIN32_EXECUTABLE TRUE
    INTERFACE_INCLUDE_DIRECTORIES "${CMAKE_CURRENT_LIST_DIR}/nwrfcsdk/include"
)
...
set(SAPNWRFC_LIB_DIR "${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/nwrfcsdk/lib")
if(${CMAKE_SYSTEM_NAME} STREQUAL "Windows")
    set(SAPNWRFC_LIB_FILES sapnwrfc.lib libsapucum.lib)
else()
    set(SAPNWRFC_LIB_FILES -lsapnwrfc -lsapucum)
endif()
target_link_directories(${PROJECT} PRIVATE ${SAPNWRFC_LIB_DIR})
...
target_link_libraries(${PROJECT}
    PRIVATE Qt6::Quick
    PRIVATE Qt6::Gui
    PRIVATE ${SAPNWRFC_LIB_FILES}
)
...
install(TARGETS ${PROJECT}
    BUNDLE DESTINATION .
    LIBRARY DESTINATION ${CMAKE_INSTALL_LIBDIR})
```

of course on my pc all works fine as i have this include folder set in PATH variable, however on another PC where these libraries are missing the app does not work

do i somehow need those libs (dlls) which i target/include against the project also set to be staticaly build in the project?

Comment: What you would typically do in such a situation is to have a 3rdparty folder relative to the project folder. In that 3rdparty folder you would have the includes and binaries respectively per 3rdparty lib you are using. Also something that could be helpful which I also did many times is to get the package config files from the 3rdparty library. That makes things easier if you are working with different OS. You then just have to use the find_package command